# What is the smallest linux OS I can use for Android development

Tags: linux, operating-system

I want to convert my old PC into linux system and use it for Android code development. The resource is very limited (256 MG) memory. Currently, PC is running on XP SP3. What is the available OS for this PC? Currently, I am using a Win8 PC for android development. It seems that I need to download some codes from google web site and all instructions are linux command line based. I may use this old turd as a code repository so that I can study other people codes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either recommend [Debian](http://www.debian.org/index.de.html) if you want a stable distribution or if you need bleeding
edge software [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org).
The wiki of Arch Linux is to my opinion better than the one of Ubuntu and Arch lets you do everything as you want it.

If you need to get started fast you can also go for Xubuntu (http:// xubuntu.org) as it is made for old hardware.

All three should run on your computer. So its just a matter of what you prefer.

Comment: Check out Puppy Linux. It might not be the tiniest linux of all, but it's the tiniest full-featured linux-- under 200MB. With constant development, and large, active user-community. There are puppy flavors based on Debian, Slackware, and Ubuntu.